# Java API for considering multiple physical drives as a single logical drive(clustered storage)

Tags: java, file

We need to store files in a particular directory on a windows machine(say `c:/datalocation`). Due to huge number of files, the c drive gets filled eventually. Now we need a location in another drive, let it be `d:/anotherstore`.

Initially we can use the following code to access the store location.

```
 File store = new File("c:/datalocation");
```

But later when we add another drive, is there any way to consider the new location as logical part of the first location?

Something like the below code.

```
store.addAnotherLocation("c:/anotherstore");
```

Here store should be able to retrieve the data from both the locations.

Comment: This isn't a Java issue, it's a file system issue. Use software RAID.

Comment: I know it's not a java issue. I want to know whether any java api supports this operation.

Comment: @Arshed It's not Java's responsibility. These would be handled on the operating system and/or server level, so you would never run out of space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no java API, but you can catch the `"Not enough disk space"` exception which would be a `IOException` and handle it by making your code to save the files in the other location. And while retrieving the files, you look in both the locations if the requested file exists.

---

Ok, if you want to randomly save in two locations, then save the file in both locations based on a `(int)(Math.random()*2);` . If you get 0 , you save in `c:/datalocation` else in `d:/otherStore`

Comment: My question is whether any API supports it. Something which abstract the entire thing. I guess out of disk-space is a common problem.

Comment: You got your answer in my answer.

Comment: Another solution given :)